# how to set expiry in IBM MQ message header using Apache Camel

Tags: ibm-mq

We are using Spring-Boot and Apache camel to connect to IBM MQ. We need to set expiry in MQMessages so that if we do  not get any response , the message should expire in 60 sec. We have added header like below :

setHeader(WMQConstants.WMQ_EXPIRY, constant(600));

But the header is being added like :

```
<usr>
<breadcrumbId>ID-ff9c1ce374f9-1544430870241-0-2</breadcrumbId>
<expiry dt='i4'>60000</expiry>
```

it is not adding to MQMD header and while browsing the message it is showing the expiry value as "-1" i.e the message will never expire.

Could you please tell me how to set MQMD header in Apache Camel?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [Camel JMS manual](http://camel.apache.org/jms.html) and having successfully used IBM MQ message expiry via Spring JMS template, you probably have to set the Camel options `explicitQosEnabled=true` and `timeToLive=60000` for a 60 seconds time-to-live.

Comment: @Sudipta Biswas: Did this answer solve your problem? If yes, please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). If not, we have to try something else.